# Parafilm vs Foil for Retaining Plate Moisture while Allowing Gas Exchange

Tags: bacteriology, cell-culture

We often plate *Streptomyces aureofaciens* and grow them in a 30°C room. A post-doc I work with has always loosely wrapped the agar plates in aluminum foil to retain moisture and prevent cracking of the agar media over extended culturing periods (up to 21 days). Another graduate student is saying that parafilm would be much better as it allows gas exchange. The post-doc agrees that parafilm would retain the moisture, but also believes the parafilm will starve the cells of oxygen over time. The parafilm we use has a reported oxygen permeability of 150 cc/m<sup>2</sup>/24 hours. I don't really know how much oxygen a plate of streptomyces would consume over a day. Thoughts?

Comment: Oxygen consumption depends on the growth rate (and *vice-versa*). If it takes very long time to culture the organism, then it probably doesn't consume oxygen that fast. Parafilm is a better choice than foils but I am not too sure about its gas permeability. As tweaks, you can use a bigger container for culturing or use a humidified incubator.

Comment: This may be a problem that is easier to solve by experiment than anything else. Make a set of cultures with parafilm and compare to a parallel set with foil. If the parafilm cells are fine, everything should be ok. If you get a significant difference in cell number or viability or something, then parafilm might not be ok. As a benefit, parafilm is cheap, so this shouldn't be a difficult experiment.